# Is it possible to assign data type to unknown variable at runtime

Tags: c#, constructor, casting, type-conversion

I am c# silverlight-5 beginner , i have a scenario in which i have used Class Node like this (which works as structure)

```
   public class Node
    {
        public Node next, left, right;
        public int symbol; // This variable will create problem
        public int freq;
    }public Node front, rear;
```

This class Node is inside another `class Huffman` Like this

```
Class Huffman
{    
       public class Node
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public int symbol; // This variable will create problem
            public int freq;
        }public Node front, rear;    
}
```

Now what i am doing next is in the constructor of huffman i receive the data type of variable "processingValue" at runtime by constructor invoke from another class. **So the data type of processingValue is decided at run time in constructor call to Huffman by another class**.

And inside the Huffman constructor i have to do something like this:

```
Class Huffman
{    
       public class Node
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public int symbol; // This variable will create problem
            public int freq;
        }public Node front, rear;  

      Huffman(AnotherClass object) //The call from another class is Huffman obj = new Huffman(this);
       {
        temp = new Node();
        temp.symbol = (processingValue); //THIS LINE CREATES PROBLEM  BECAUSE DATA TYPE OF "symbol" is int and may be data type of processingValue could be "short"/"long"/"UInt"etc. 
       }  
}
```

Is there any way to type cast the data type of "symbol" make it of "processingValue's" data type ?

I mean in `Node Class` if i set symbol's data type to `"Type"` or any other and then i change it's data type in constructor making it same as data type of processingValue ?
By run time i mean it's a silverlight application and i have comboBox to select from the limited data type (among short/int/long/Uint) on running the program and then the control go to the Huffman constructor with the respective data type selected in combo box

**Is it possibe to do ? ** A big thanks for help.

Comment: How about trying to use `dynamic` type ? Let me know if it works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Can you define, _decided at run time_ ? You mean you are creating a newly type with the type builder? Or do you mean decided by the programmer when using this type without modifying the `Node` class. In that case, take a look at generics.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen By run time i mean it's a silverlight application and  i have comboBox to select from the limited data type (among short/int/long/Uint) on running the program and then the control go to the Huffman constructor with the respective data type selected in combo box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` type to make sure the data type of `symbol` is actually determined at runtime.

```
public dynamic symbol;
```

By doing so, the following assignments will all be valid:

```
symbol = (long) 100;
symbol = (int) 100;
symbol = (uint) 100;
```

Comment: do i need to include any library for it ?

Comment: You don't, the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of the .NET Framework starting at version 4.0.

Comment: Just as a side-note, only *one* of those 3 assignments can be valid at a time - you can't execute all three. You can't assign a long and *then* and int.

Comment: Why not use the ordinary `Object` because the chosen type are simpletypes as I read from above.

Comment: Error 1 Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported FinalSS

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You could, but you'd then have to cast up from `object` every time you consume the property. By using the DLR, your object actually resembles the type straight away.

Comment: Error 3 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll? corresponding to line in my code : " if (pt.symbol.Equals(processingValue))" (it's if condition)

Comment: @user234839 Make sure you have those references set up in your project.

Comment: @aevitas Thanks for the answer, Yes it worked but the problem was actually different, I was trying to do the same using generics when i was not able to solve that problem then i am obliged  to do using this way. Could you please try to answer me on this link (No body is able to answer that question yet) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899744/issues-with-generics-using-silverlight

Comment: @user234839 I will have a look at it. If you really want your question answered, consider placing a bounty on it. :)

Comment: @aevitas I am not eligible for bounty right now. And it is must to solve soon . And i am not able to understand why it gives problem even  i implemented the same in console application and  every thing works fine  in console application

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `Object` instead of `Dynamic`. I would only use Dynamics in combination with complex types from other languages.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node next, left, right;
    public object symbol; // This variable will create problem
    public int freq;
}
```

Comment: @Jeoren Little sample please ? i am not able to understand yet.

Comment: You may want to edit the code sample, right now it's identical to the one in the question.

Comment: I was applying a few spelling edits to your answer, maybe they conflicted with your edits. Sorry!